# ¿cómo puedo cambiar los valores de mi gráfica con Scale cuando ingreso por valores en un Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, scale

Cordial saludo compañeros;

Hace un tiempo estoy creando un código para analizar el comportamiento de un motor a través de sus gráficas características. Al ingresar valores en el Entry y presionar el RadioButton genera la gráfica perfectamente, aunque, como ultimo paso, quisiera que cuando se genera la gráfica, pueda modificar los valores a través de un control deslizante.

Sin embargo, por mas que lo he intentado estos días no consigo que al ingresar los datos y graficar, se cree el scroll para cambiar los valores en un cierto rango. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import math

from tkinter import Tk, Frame, IntVar, Label, Entry, Radiobutton, Toplevel, DoubleVar, Button

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


def corriente_vs_velocidad(Am, r1, x1, r0, xm, r2, x2):
    jx2 = x2 * 1j
    voltaje_fase = Am / math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo = 1800
    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm / math.sqrt(r1 ** 2 + (x1 + xm) ** 2))
    zth = ((xm * 1j) * (r1 + x1 * 1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm) * 1j)
    rth, xth = zth.real, zth.imag
    s = np.arange(0.001, 1, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s) * n_sincronismo
    I2 = (vth) / ((rth + (r2 / s)) + (xth + jx2))
    return nm, I2


def torque_vs_velocidad(Am, r1, x1, r0, xm, r2, x2):
    n_sincronismo = 1800
    voltaje_fase = Am / math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

    # Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.
    zs = r1 + x1*1j
    z0 = (r0*xm*1j)/(r0 + xm*1j)

    vth = voltaje_fase * z0 / (zs + z0)
    zth = z0*zs / (z0 + zs)
    rth = zth.real
    xth = zth.imag

    s = np.arange(-1.0, 1.5, 0.001)
    nm = (1 - s) * n_sincronismo

    # Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.

    torque = ((3 * vth ** 2 * r2) / s) / (
    n_sincronismo_rad * ((rth + (r2) / s) ** 2 + (xth + x2) ** 2)
)

    return nm, torque

def tension_fuente1(Am):

    x = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.0001)
    V1 = (Am*np.sin(x))
    return x, V1

def tension_fuente2(Am):
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.0001)
    V2 = Am*np.sin(x+(120*np.pi)/180)
    return x, V2

def tension_fuente3(Am):
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.0001)
    V3 = Am*np.sin(x+(240*np.pi)/180)
    return x, V3

def fp_rotor(r2, x2):

    s = np.arange(0.001,1,0.0001)
    nm = (1 - s)*1800

    x = np.tan(s*r2/x2)
    fpr = (np.cos(x)) #deberia ser XR0 y no XR. Consultar con el tutor.

    return nm, fpr

class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("ANALISIS DEL MOTOR DE INDUCCION EN REGIMEN PERMANENTE")
        self.geometry("1265x680+0+0")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        self.selec = IntVar()
        var1 = DoubleVar()
        var2 = DoubleVar()
        var3 = DoubleVar()

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.config(width=260, height=690, bg="red")
        frame1.pack(side="left")

        Label(frame1, text="PARAMETROS DEL MOTOR").place(x=55, y=20)

        Label(frame1, text="Tension:").place(x=2, y=280)

        self.amp_entrada = Entry(frame1)
        self.amp_entrada.place(x=62, y=280)

        Label(frame1, text="R1:").place(x=2, y=70)

        self.r_stator = Entry(frame1)
        self.r_stator.place(x=32, y=70)

        Label(frame1, text="X1:").place(x=2, y=100)

        self.x_stator = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_stator.place(x=32, y=100)

        Label(frame1, text="R0:").place(x=2, y=320)

        self.r_nucleo = Entry(frame1)
        self.r_nucleo.place(x=32, y=320)

        Label(frame1, text="Xm:").place(x=2, y=150)

        self.x_nucleo = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_nucleo.place(x=32, y=150)

        Label(frame1, text="X2:").place(x=2, y=200)

        self.x_rotor = Entry(frame1)
        self.x_rotor.place(x=32, y=200)

        Label(frame1, text="R2:").place(x=2, y=230)

        self.r_rotor = Entry(frame1)
        self.r_rotor.place(x=32, y=230)

        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.config(width=1100, height=840, bg = "pink")
        frame2.place(x=261,y=-170)

        fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(14, 14), dpi=72)
        fig.patch.set_facecolor("xkcd:white")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ax0 = fig.add_axes(
        (0.25, 0.25, 0.50, 0.50), facecolor=(0.75, 0.75, 0.75), frameon=False
    )


        frame3 = Frame(self)
        frame3.config(width=1100, height=40, bg = "blue")
        frame3.place(x=260,y=0)

        pantalla1 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = var1, state = "disable")
        pantalla1.place(x = 50, y = 5)

        pantalla2 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = var2, state = "disable")
        pantalla2.place(x = 250, y = 5)

        pantalla3 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = var3, state = "disable")
        pantalla3.place(x = 450, y = 5)

        pantalla4 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = var3, state = "disable")
        pantalla4.place(x = 650, y = 5)

        pantalla5 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = var3, state = "disable")
        pantalla5.place(x = 850, y = 5)

        frame4 = Frame(self)
        frame4.config(width=1050, height=40, bg = "green")
        frame4.place(x=260,y=640)

        torque_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame4,
            text="Par vs Velocidad",
            value=2,
            bg = "white",
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )
        torque_radiobuton.place(x=5, y=7)

        corriente_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame4,
            text="Corriente vs Velocidad",
            value=1,
            bg = "white",
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )

        corriente_radiobuton.place(x=290, y=7)

        tension_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame4,
            text="Tension de entrada",
            value=3,
            bg = "white",
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )

        tension_radiobuton.place(x=145, y=7)

        fp_radiobuton = Radiobutton(
            frame4,
            text="Factor de potencia del rotor",
            value=4,
            bg = "white",
            variable=self.selec,
            command=self.select_plot,
        )

        fp_radiobuton.place(x=470, y=7)

    def select_plot(self):
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        value = self.selec.get()

        Am = float(self.amp_entrada.get())
        r1 = float(self.r_stator.get())  # resistencia del estator.
        x1 = float(self.x_stator.get())  # reactancia del estator.
        r0 = float(self.r_nucleo.get())
        xm = float(self.x_nucleo.get())  # reactancia del circuito tanque.
        r2 = float(self.r_rotor.get())  # resistencia del rotor.
        x2 = float(self.x_rotor.get())  # reactancia del rotor.

        self.ax0.clear()
        self.ax0.patch.set_visible(False)
        self.ax0.grid(True)


        if value == 1:
            x, y = corriente_vs_velocidad(Am, r1, x1, r0, xm, r2, x2)
            self.ax0.set_title("Curva Corriente vs Velocidad")
            self.ax0.set_xlabel("Velocidad sincrona - RPM", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.set_ylabel("Corriente del rotor - A", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.axhline(color="black")
            self.ax0.axvline(color="black")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y)
            self.canvas.draw()


        elif value == 2:
            x, y = torque_vs_velocidad(Am, r1, x1, r0, xm, r2, x2)
            self.ax0.set_title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
            self.ax0.set_xlabel("Velocidad sincrona - RPM", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.set_ylabel("Torque inducido - N.M", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.axhline(0, color="black")
            self.ax0.axvline(0, color="black")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color="r")
            self.canvas.draw()

        elif value == 3:
            x, y = tension_fuente1(Am)
            x, y1 = tension_fuente2(Am)
            x, y2 = tension_fuente3(Am)
            self.ax0.set_title("Tension de entrada")
            self.ax0.set_xlabel("Tiempo - Rad", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.set_ylabel("Amplitud - V", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color="red")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y1, linewidth=1, color="blue")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y2, linewidth=1, color="green")
            self.canvas.draw()

        elif value == 4:
            x, y = fp_rotor(x2,r2)
            self.ax0.set_title("Factor de potencia del rotor")
            self.ax0.set_xlabel("Velocidad sincrona - RPM", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.set_ylabel("magnitud del factor de potencia - Rad", fontsize = 9)
            self.ax0.axhline(0, color="black")
            self.ax0.axvline(0, color="black")
            self.ax0.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color="red")
            self.canvas.draw()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Gui()
    root.mainloop()
```

La variable a la cual pretendo variar el valor para ver el comportamiento de la curva es la R2. Ej: si le asigno el valor a R2 de 0.332, al salir la gráfica pueda aparece un Scale que me permita variar ese valor puntual de 0.1 a 0.5

Cordial saludo y gracias por la atención prestada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es demasiado extenso para reproducir de nuevo aquí la nueva versión, pero basta indicar algunos cambios que le hice:

## Pequeña mejora de usabilidad

- Añadí a cada `Entry` un `.bind()` para que cuando se pulse INTRO (ENTER) en esa entrada, se llame a una función `on_enter()`. Eso me permitirá redibujar la gráfica si se altera el valor de cualquier entrada (siempre que el usuario pulse ENTER para confirmar la entrada, si simplemente se va luego a otra, aunque la entrada cambió de valor, no se redibujará).

  Esto se implementa por ejemplo así (muestro sólo un caso, pero se añadiría código similar en todas las `Entry`)

  ```
      Label(frame1, text="Tension:").place(x=2, y=280)

      self.amp_entrada = Entry(frame1)
      self.amp_entrada.place(x=62, y=280)
      self.amp_entrada.bind('<Key-Return>', self.on_enter)   # <-- Añadido
  ```
- Escribir el código de la función `self.on_enter()`, que se limita a llamar a la que pinta los gráficos. Es necesario programar esta función intermedia porque el bind le enviará un parámetro (evento) que la que pinta gráficos no necesita.

  ```
      def on_enter(self, event):
          self.select_plot()
  ```
- Modificar la función que pinta el gráfico para que no dé errores si aún no hay valores en las entradas de parámetros. Basta capturar (e ignorar) las excepciones que puedan producirse al leer los parámetros.

  ```
      def select_plot(self):
          print("Select plot called!")
          self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
          value = self.selec.get()
          try:
              Am = float(self.amp_entrada.get())
              r1 = float(self.r_stator.get())  # resistencia del estator.
              x1 = float(self.x_stator.get())  # reactancia del estator.
              r0 = float(self.r_nucleo.get())
              xm = float(self.x_nucleo.get())  # reactancia del circuito tanque.
              r2 = float(self.r_rotor.get())  # resistencia del rotor.
              x2 = float(self.x_rotor.get())  # reactancia del rotor.
          except:
              return

  # El resto sigue igual y no lo copio
  ```

## Añadido de la *scale*

La escala para modificar R2 se añade con el siguiente código:

```
        self.r_rotor_scale = Scale(
            frame1, from_=0.1, to=1.5, resolution=0.1,
            orient=HORIZONTAL,
            command=self.on_scale_change)
        self.r_rotor_scale.place(x=32, y=360)
        Label(frame1, text="R2:").place(x=2, y=360)
```

Esto crea una escala con extremos fijos (entre 0.1 y 1.5) que varía a saltos de 0.1. Cada vez que su valor cambie (porque el usuario deslizó la escala) se ejecutará la función `on_scale_change`, que debemos programar a continuación.

Esa función recibe como parámetro el nuevo valor de la escala, y lo usará para cambiar el valor de la Entry correspondiente a R2, y para llamar de nuevo a la función que pinta el gráfico:

```
    def on_scale_change(self, value):
        self.r_rotor.delete(0,END)
        self.r_rotor.insert(0,str(value))
        self.select_plot()
```

Con esto ya tendrías (creo) lo que pedías, pues al deslizar esa escala se verá cómo la entrada R2 va cambiando de valor, y a la vez cómo se actualiza la gráfica en su panel.